# Cannot add domain to field

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, domains

So I created my domain with coded values for my file geodatabase. I go to the feature class properties, fields tab, I create a new field, verify the data type of the field and domain matches and add that domain in the field properties below, click OK. Everything happens smoothly.

Now when I immediately reopen the same feature class properties I don't see the domain I set 1 minute ago. The domain field is empty and I can see in the ArcMap attribute table that the domain is not set to that field at all. And also now I can't edit or change any property of that field. It seems kind of locked.

This happens every time I set a domain to a field. Why is the domain disappearing? What am I doing wrong? The feature class is pre-created and I just want to add new field and add the domain to that field.

Answer (score 1):

Okay So I finally figured out the problem. There was a difference in the Arcmap version I was creating the domain on (10.0) and the Arcmap version the features were created on (10.2). When I created the domain on 10.2 everything worked fine.